# pre_order_traversal vs post_order_traversal

Tags: python, traversal

I have the two functions below
"PRE_ORDER_TRAVERSAL"

```
def pre_order_traversal(root: Node):
    if root is not None:
        print(root.val)
        pre_order_traversal(root.left)
        pre_order_traversal(root.right)
```

"POST_ORDER_TRAVERSAL":

```
def post_order_traversal(root: Node):
    if root is not None:
        post_order_traversal(root.left)
        post_order_traversal(root.right)
        print(root.val)
```

So for post order traversal , it is a recursive call that runs root.left and adds it to the call stack all the way until there are no more root.lefts and does the same for root.right and then the print.val just .pops each value from the stack?

If so, how does python or where is python instructing it to do down a level in the tree? As well what is the datatype for root.left to hold multiple values? I get it is recursive having trouble understanding the operations to actually enable so much going on -- it does not seem like enough code to eanble the above.

For instance -- if this is the input:

```
5 4 3 x x 8 x x 6 x x
```

how does it know to go from 4 to 3?

Comment: root is the current level(it is only the true root before it calls recursively) ... so root.left/root.right is down a level from root

Comment: and then it keeps going down? How does it go deeper & deeper?

Comment: Have you tried tracing the recursive calls on a piece of paper or a whiteboard using a sample tree? There's no better way to understand it.

Comment: I have and I am writing the code and tracing the input , I conceptually get it -- but what in python is actually directing or how does the code  (root.left) just know to go deeper? Also, Tom Karzes -- thanks for the input but does "this really couldn't be simpler" add any value, comments like that just make me feel bad about myself and more distracted from learning - was that your intention?

Comment: Hey @0004 did you try to use another param to hold root level or you can also try to store each sub root value in an array then print it at the end, array will help you to work with the indexes

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to understand what is a node.
Here is a simple example for the Node class:

```
class Node():
    left: Node = None
    right: Node = None
    value: int = None
   
   def __init__(self, value):
        value = value


tree = Node(3)
tree.left = Node(2)
tree.right = Node(5)
tree.right.right = Node(7)
```

This code will give you the tree:

```
    3
   /  \
  2    5
        \
         7
```

Each iteration in the function you print the value of the node and send recursively the sons to the same function.

It passes over the tree, each time it gets just one specific node, and if it isn't None - the functio handles it and sends the 2 sides to the same function. The difference between the pre/post order is when it treats the current Node (the print in your example)

Comment: thank you so so much for this -- so essentially your saying that think of recursion of going like "tree.right" , "tree.right.right" until  let's say "tree.right.right.right" a None value?